# SQL imported french accented characters as special character. Can this be reversed?

Tags: sql, unicode, ascii, special-characters, collation

I imported a piece of text which include accents into my SQL database. My DB has its collation set as SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

The column I imported the text into is an NVARCHAR column and also has the collation set to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS.

Here is the text:

```
Frères Ltée
```

And here is how it was imported:

```
Fr+¿res Lt+¬e
```

I was hoping to reverse the text back to its original form. Are you able to help with that or know why this occurred?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue;

I was able to resolve my issue by using the ACP parameter when importing my data:

```
BULK INSERT [Table]
FROM 'FilePath'
WITH
(

  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
  ROWS_PER_BATCH = 10000, 
  FIRSTROW = 0,
  TABLOCK,
  CODEPAGE = 'ACP'
)
```